# Able to delete file in specific directory using VBScript

Tags: vbscript, windows-server-2008-r2

I've attempted to delete old logs files from my log directory, but nothing happens. I used the same exact code with the exception of changing the file location and it deleted those files just fine. I'm running the script via CMD which I'm running as administrator. I'm not sure why it works in one directory and not the other when I executing the script as the Administrator.

```
iMaxAge = 30   'in days
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set colFolder = objFSO.GetFolder(sLogFolder)
For Each colSubfolder In colFolder.SubFolders
        Set objFolder = objFSO.GetFolder(colSubfolder.Path)
        Set colFiles = objFolder.Files
        For Each objFile In colFiles
                iFileAge = Now - objFile.DateCreated
                If iFileAge > (iMaxAge+1) Then
                        objFSO.DeleteFile objFile, True
                End iIf
        Next
Next
```

When `sLogFolder = "c:\inetpub\logs\LogFiles"` it works.

When `sLogFolder = "c:\www\logs\LogFiles"` it doesn't work.

This is being done on a Window 2008 R2 server.

Comment: Is there an error?  (remember to remove any `resume next`) Print something within the loops to see where its failing

Comment: Did you compare permissions on both folders?

Comment: There's no error. The script runs to completion, but nothing happens when in the c:\www directory. I did do a permissions comparison and the administrator user has the same permissions in both directories and subdirectories and files. There is an extra user in the inetpub directory permissions list but it doesn't seem to exist anywhere else so I can't add it to the other directory.

Comment: The script does not clean  `sLogFolder` itself but only its _subfolders_. Maybe that `colFolder.SubFolders` collection is empty i.e. check `Wscript.Echo  colFolder.SubFolders.Count`.

Comment: Thanks @JosefZ. I wasn't able to print to the console so I couldn't troubleshoot. After using Wscript.Echo I found out that the DateCreated was wrong on the files and I needed to use the DateLastModified property.